# Wordpress dynamic widget by location?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, widgets

i need to show the widget based on user location , for a testing purpose i have created the by using following code

```
if( function_exists( 'register_sidebar' ) )
register_sidebar( array( 'name'=>'Madurai-Right',
'before_widget' => '<div class="widget relativ">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h2>',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );
```

and getting the widget like below

```
<?php $city="Madurai";  echo $side_bar= "'$city-Right'"; ?>
    <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar($side_bar) ) :?>
    &nbsp;
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here city is the location, so based on the location i am getting the sidebar as `dynamic_sidebar($side_bar)` it doesn't working

But if i use without the variable ase `dynamic_sidebar('Madurai-Right')` is working well, any idea? what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1):

try to make a simpler code: change

```
$side_bar= "'$city-Right'";
```

to

```
$side_bar= $city . '-Right';
```

you have extra `'` in `$side_bar`, the way you've done would give you `'Madurai-Right'` but you need `Madurai-Right`, this way

```
dynamic_sidebar($side_bar)
```

would be like writing

```
dynamic_sidebar("'Madurai-Right'")
```

while you only need

```
dynamic_sidebar("Madurai-Right")
```

besides, always avoid variable substitution, concatenation is always more secure.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i've updated the answer